# drawing a pipe that passes a given array of 3D-points

Tags: opengl, model, 3d, path

I have as input an array of 3D points. And I need to draw a pipe that connects those points with each other so the first point is connected to the second one, the second to the third, ... The pipe has a square-shape (not a cilinder, but more a cuboid-shape like this [figure](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21SDDwmYMiL._SL500_AA280_.jpg)) with a width of d. And the difference between two points goes always in just one direction (so when deltaX != 0 that means deltaY == 0  and deltaZ == 0).

What are the OpenGL commands to draw this model?

Comment: Should the pipe be a set of straight sections 'welded' together at the points, or a single smooth curve?

Comment: a set of straight sections welded together at the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the [GLE Tubing and Extrusion Library](http://linas.org/gle/) a try.

Answer (score -1):

OpenGL has no high-level primitives such as square-shaped pipes. If you manage to decompose your pipe into triangles, you can find all the commands you need in the [tutorials on opengl.org](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorials).